# change size of UINavigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I Went through the apple documentation of UINavigation Bar but didnt find anything related to its size. How can we decrease its size from the regular size? I have changed its font and text size in the app delegate file but unable to change the size.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Is there anyway to change its size?

Answer (score 2):

From [Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html):

> It is not permissible to change the navigation bar object or modify
>   its bounds, frame, or alpha values directly.

However, there are a few properties that you can modify, including the following:

- [barStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barStyle) property
- [translucent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/translucent) property
- [tintColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/tintColor) property

But you can modify custom navigation bar and below is some available library with swift:

1. https://github.com/remirobert/RRMaterialNavigationBar
2. https://github.com/bitomule/BTNavigationExtendedPanel

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the navigation bar frame size.(i.e height or width). if you customize you app default behavior. App store may reject you app. For add hoc distribution you can customize.